# How to install Epson L210 scanner in Ubuntu 20.04 using terminal command?

Tags: printing, scanner, epson

How to install Epson L210 scanner in Ubuntu 20.4 using terminal command? I'm a new Linux user. recently I've installed Ubuntu 20.4 in my laptop. I tried several times to install the .deb file, but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: What errors did you get can we see it (copy and paste into you question)?

Comment: pls see the attachment.

Comment: Please open a terminal and run ```sudo apt install -f``` and after try to install it again (close and open that installation window)! Remember this is a new OS release so some issues will exist

Comment: still not working !

Comment: You are trying to install `epson-printer-utility` that is not related to scanner at all. So the question doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Epson scan software has a dependency on the "sane" package, (according to the manual). Try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sane
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Epson does not (yet) have a package for Ubuntu 20.04, only for previous Ubuntu versions. I successfully installed another Epson Scanner (DS-1630) on Ubuntu 20.04 by cloning from https://gitlab.com/utsushi/utsushi/, then build and install (as per instructions in README).

Test from the command line with

```
$ sane-find-scanner
$ scanimage -L
$ utsushi --no-interface --doc-source='ADF' --duplex --resolution=150 ~/test.pdf
```

Next to-do for me: to use a sane frontend or utsushi as graphical interface

Comment: Packages for 19.10 install with no problem on 20.04.

Comment: While the package for 19.10 **installed** fine on 20.04, the scanner worked only very unreliably. Meanwhile I noted that also the version compiled from source does not work reliably, at leat not with the GUI (utsushi/imagescanv3 or xsane).

As the 19.10 package works for you (assuming not only the install worked), either something else in my setup is flawed or it is an issue specific to the DS-1630. Good to know and encouragement to look for a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install **Epson Printer Utility** that is not related to the scanner at all.

Also you are trying to install a 32-bit package to a 64-bit system, that is also wrong.